# Web platform for Client Server Model

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, d3.js

I m working on developing a UI which could visualize a client server model. Specifically I have a system which currently issues some commands from server to client. I wish to visualize in web platform specifically

1. Displaying a connected graph between server and its clients or between clients such that they are drag and drop component.
2. If i wish to issue any command to client, I could do that using right click on server and say "update client-1 with new Software patch" or "add a new client".

Currently, I did some basic POC in d3.js, but i'm unable to get my expected result, I could only represent a model/connected graph between client and server. I am also aware of drag and drop feature of angularJS, but can i have a right click action on my draggable component which will internally call backend engine and process my request.

Could someone please point me to any such platform/ library which can fulfill my requirement ?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Angular has nothing to do with drag/drop. You are describing `contextmenu` event in the dom

Comment: thanks for pointing to contextmenu, i'm not specifically bound to any UI framework, but i trying to understand if right click action will work and display me some custom options.

Comment: It is an event available in the dom  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/contextmenu Should be easy to find numerous custom display scripts for it